# Time it takes to load data from prom

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga, vlsi

I'm working on multibooting of FPGA , I"m sending a sequence of commands and during the middle I need to load data from PROM memory. I am specifying the address from which the data should be loaded. SO my question is How many clock cycles does prom take to load bit file from the memory to the FPGA fabric ??

[Reconfiguration of FPGA in ML605 Board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153614/reconfiguration-of-fpga-in-ml605-board) : Here is the link, in case if you need more information.

Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Electronics SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In most of FPGAs, loading data from host computer is a time consuming task as it loads the data in serial manner. This means that each bit of the memory requires at least one JTAG cycle to be transferred from host computer to the FPGA. I know that JTAG has frequency of ~100MHz in some advanced Altera FPGAs, hence, for large memories it might take few second to load all contents.